# setBackgroundResource or setImageResource for animationDrawable

Tags: android

I have an imageview that has wrap_content for the width and height. I want to add animationDrawable.

Should I use `setBackgroundResource()` or `setImageResource()`?

I have searched SO for differences and it talks about possibly stretching in case of background. However my image is `wrap_content`, so would there be any difference?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want the the ImageView to retain the size that you initially gave it (by its current `android:src` attribute drawble) use `setImageResource()`.

If you apply the animation drawable to the background via `setBackgroundResource()`,  the animation drawable WILL scale to fit exactly in the size of the ImageView.  And unless that animation drawable matches the aspect ratio of the ImageView dimensions (very unlikely) it will not look uniform and appear stretched.

Comment: Thanks Petey, but wouldn't the imageview be like the imagesize dimensions anyways when I am doing wrap_content? I dont understand whywould they be different? What confused me is that the offical documentation uses the background as an example for the animation